# Animation Nodes - Trigger Armature’s instances action?

Tags: animation, node-editor, armature, animation-nodes, actions

I have quite a complicated shot to do: as the camera moves in the scene, hundreds of props are constructing themselves. One same props can be like 50 times in the scene.

What I did for now is create one animated object in one blend file, then linked it in the master scene, place it as I wish, offset the armature’s action, and restart all over again with a symlink of the object’s file. (Unless Blender won’t allow me to offset one action by props). 
With all the symlinks it’s becoming to look like a mess an I’m sure this can easily be done with Animation Nodes.

**So, is there a way to trigger armature’s action with offset for each instances of an armature ?**

For example, if the distance between the camera and the instance’s object is less than 10 units, then fire the action. Or a simple delay can be enough.

For now I successfully instanced the armatures and spawned them in my scenes but the objects don’t follow their bones ( I suspect because they are parented to the bones not skinned with a modifier). And I have no clue how to trigger or delayed animation’s instances.

Thanks for your help.